# Identifying a CAT6 cable in a bundle

Tags: networking, cable, cat5, cat5e, cat6

We had a contractor wire up our office with all the cables leading back to a central location. The only problem is that he didn't label anything, so we have no idea which cables go to which room. One end of the cable is terminated in a wall-jack (in the rooms), the other end is un-terminated and will be punched to a patch panel. Is there a way to identify the cables without having to terminate them? We'd like to group the cables on the patch panel by room, but I don't want to crimp/punch each cable twice. Thanks!

Comment: Can you get a cable toner?

Comment: I'd rather not have to buy anything, but I do have a multi-meter. Could we do something with a battery and a multi-meter or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get a tone generator ([http://www.amazon.com/Fluke-Networks-PRO3000-Tone-Probe/dp/B000FTADX0/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1383596496&sr=8-1&keywords=tone+generator](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FTADX0)) and plug that into the terminated end and use the probe to find the cables on the other end.

And anytime a cable is pulled make sure the installer plans to label them cables in a manageable way (I've done site visits before even accepting a bid for work to make sure the installer does quality work)

Comment: Agreed. The scope of work should include labeling of both ends of the cable being installed. It should also include certifying the cabling.

Comment: I agree, and I missed this when arranging the installation. Let's just say that they did the minimum amount of work possible.

Comment: A tone generator is definitely the way to go. I'll have to grab one at Home Depot or something to finish this job correctly, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of punching down the entire cable, just punch down one wire (of the 8 in the CAT6 cable), e.g. the orange one, then cut open a patch cable, plug it into one plug and then electrically test that connection (using testing leads, a 9V battery and a little lightbulb/buzzer.

Comment: Hmmm. I think using a tone/probe would be a lot simpler and less intrusive.